# Проблема с отрисовкой в OpenGl

Tags: opengl, glsl

Пытаюсь отрендерить облака как в майнкрафт, однако на большом расстоянии появляются артефакты на стыках (фотографии ниже), как это можно решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В близи выглядит намного лучше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как минимум 2 варианта: Увеличить глубину Z буфера. Рисовать нижнюю плоскость отдельно и без Z-теста.

Comment: @Kromster пытался изменить буфер глубины с помощью glDepthRange, но буфер глубины вообще сбился, но вроде основная проблема исправилась. Подскажи пожалуйста, что я делаю не так